# Opening Range ATR

Tags: pine-script

I'm looking to convert this ThinkScript statement into PineScript. It calculates the opening range ATR using 3 values (orHigh = opening range high, orClose = opening range close, orLow =  opening range low)

```
def orATR = MovingAverage(AverageType.WILDERS, TrueRange(orHigh, orClose, orLow), 5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the PineScript there are functions `atr()` and `tr()`.
Check which one suits you best.